# Creating symmetric autocorrelation matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation, autocorrelation

I am performing an autocorrelation process for a vector of time series data. I am looking to create a symmetric matrix composed of autocorrelation for a given time series.

I am using the `acf()` function to check my values and it returns:

Autocorrelations of series ‘acfData’, by lag

```
     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12     13 
 1.000 -0.038  0.253  0.266  0.250  0.267 -0.182  0.281 -0.013 -0.067 -0.122 -0.115 -0.023 -0.337
```

To achieve the matrix I then perform a data.frame change on the data to allow me to slide the values by whatever specified lag:

```
dataF <- data.frame("data" = acfData)
names(dataF)[1] <- "acfData"
dataLag <- slide(dataF, "acfData", slideBy = -1)
```

To give:

```
> head(dataLag)
  acfData acfData-1
1      -7        NA
2       5        -7
3       4         5
4     -17         4
5       6       -17
6     -10         6
```

This gives the correct 2x2 matrix when I just perform a `cor()` function:

```
> cor(na.omit(dataLag))
              acfData   acfData-1
acfData    1.00000000 -0.03842146
acfData-1 -0.03842146  1.00000000
```

However expanding this to a second time lag matrix results in the previous values changing.

```
    dataLag <- cbind(dataLag, slide(dataF, "acfData", slideBy = -2)[2])
> head(dataLag)
      acfData acfData-1 acfData-2
    1      -7        NA        NA
    2       5        -7        NA
    3       4         5        -7
    4     -17         4         5
    5       6       -17         4
    6     -10         6       -17
```

Performing the `cor()` function again results in:

```
> cor(na.omit(dataLag))
              acfData   acfData-1   acfData-2
acfData    1.00000000 -0.03156163  0.27502462
acfData-1 -0.03156163  1.00000000 -0.07361449
acfData-2  0.27502462 -0.07361449  1.00000000
```

As you can see the 1 step lagged data correlation has changed. I assume this is due to the `na.omit()` maybe removing the whole first two rows due to the intro of the second lag giving two `NA`s, but I am not sure how to omit them correctly for the first lag calculation.

Comment: maybe try `cor(dataLag,use="pairwise.complete.obs")` ?

Comment: You may want to consider the `ccf` function - see `?ccf`

Comment: Hi Ben, that worked perfectly. I will attach an answer showing the final for future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Ben Bolker in the comments, simply adding the 'use' argument of "pairwise.complete.obs" gives the correct omitting of NAs.

The new return for the function is:

```
> cor(dataLag, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
              acfData   acfData-1   acfData-2
acfData    1.00000000 -0.03842146  0.27502462
acfData-1 -0.03842146  1.00000000 -0.07361449
acfData-2  0.27502462 -0.07361449  1.00000000
```